# Setting the viewBox for an SVG image with just CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG being loaded into the background of a CSS pseudo element like this:

```
.sorting_asc:after {
    content: '';
    float: right;
    background: url(../svg/sort-asc.svg) no-repeat;
    height: 8px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

Is there a way I can set the `viewBox` for this SVG with just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
background: url(../svg/sort-asc.svg#svgView(viewBox(a,b,c,d))) no-repeat;
```

provided you replace a,b,c,d with appropriate numeric values for your viewBox. This is called an [SVG fragment identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG)

Comment: this isnt working for me in Chrome :( must admit Ive not tested it in other browsers

Comment: Is there a cross browser solution?  A fix that only works in Firefox is not a fix in my mind

Comment: If that doesn't work in other UAs then I guess there isn't.